# Error while loading a specific json file in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to open and load an JSON file ("evenement.json") with Python so that I can process the data. However, I get some errors while using either pandas or json in Python.

- For pandas, I get this error `ValueError: Expected object or value` when using **read_json**.
- For json, I get this error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` when using the following codes:

```
with open('evenement_original.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data['IDEES_SORTIE'])
    f.close()
```

Here is the link to the JSON file: [evenement.json](https://carte.ville.quebec.qc.ca/DonneesOuvertes/evenement.json)

I also try making temp.json with a similar format but the codes run without any errors.

***temp.json***

```
{
  "test": {
    "details": [
      {
        "number": "1",
        "color": "red"
      },
      {
        "number": "2",
        "color": "green"
      },
      {
        "number": "3",
        "color": "yellow"
      },
      {
        "number": "4",
        "color": "blue"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

To fix this, I try keeping only the array (within the **[..]**) in the .json file and it works normally. Still, I would love if anyone knows why the error happen. Thank you!!

Comment: There's a BOM character at the beginning of the file.

Comment: You need to save the file without that character.

Comment: You file was encoded using `utf-8-sig`.